# How to remove vertical separators in html bar?

Tags: html, css

I have a horitzontal bar with the following html code in a blog:

```css
#menuh {
 background: #D8D8D8;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 1px;
 display:block;
 height:auto;
 text-align:center;
}
#menuh li {
 display: inline;
 font: 67.5% Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 44px 0 44px;;
 padding: 0px;
}
#menuh a {
 background: #D8D8D8
 url()no-repeat left top;margin:0 1.5px 0 1.5px;padding:0 0 0 7px;text-decoration:none; ) bottom right no-repeat;
 color: #0B615E; 
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 5px 23.8px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 14px;
}
#menuh a:hover {
 background: #A9D0F5 url() bottom center no-repeat;    
 color: #aeaab0    
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="mh">
   <ul id="menuh">
   <li><a href="http://adress1">adress1</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://adress2">adress2</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://adress3">adress3</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://adress4">adress4</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The output of this code is:

[image]

I would like to remove those vertical separators, but don't know how. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your CSS.

Comment: The render of the snippet is not the same as the image, you forgot something maybe. Btw try `#menuh li, #menuh a { border: none; }`

Comment: Your menu doesn't render inline.  Change the rule for `#menuh a` to `display: inline-block`.  Then from your example above I don't see any vertical bars.  Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9jfch7oL/

Comment: They appear when I add this code to blogger. Sorry for the syntax errors. Most of the code has been collected on the internet and I'm really a newbie with it. Adding border: none; as suggested by Bob0t solved the problem. If you write it in a separate answer I'll be able to mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

its working for me try this

```css
#menuh {
 background: #D8D8D8;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 1px;
 display:block;
 height:auto;
 text-align:center;
}
#menuh li {
 float: left;
 font: 67.5% Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 44px 0 44px;;
 padding: 0px;
}
#menuh a {
 background: #D8D8D8
 url()no-repeat left top;margin:0 1.5px 0 1.5px;padding:0 0 0 7px;text-decoration:none; ) bottom right no-repeat;
 color: #0B615E; 
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 5px 23.8px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 14px;
}
#menuh a:hover {
 background: #A9D0F5 url() bottom center no-repeat;    
 color: #aeaab0    
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="mh">
   <ul id="menuh">
   <li><a href="http://adress1">adress1</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://adress2">adress2</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://adress3">adress3</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://adress4">adress4</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: background: #D8D8D8
 url()no-repeat left top;margin:0 1.5px 0 1.5px;padding:0 0 0 7px;text-decoration:none; ) bottom right no-repeat; ?

Comment: I have to debug it. I took it from somewhere. Don't really know the reason. Thanks a lot for the code, Bilal. However the verticals separators still appear when I add it to blogger. As I commented before, using #menuh a { border: none; } solved the problem.